# /users - fromdate/todate broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

consider:

All users on meta :  "total": 18923,

http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users?sort=creation&order=desc

Users created on meta in the last month: "total": 18923,

http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users?sort=creation&order=desc&fromdate=1274079600&todate=1276758000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed.